# qmake INSTALL's option to install if file not exists (qt .pro option)

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm using the install option of qmake to define the "make install" behaviour of the generated Makefile, for example in myProject.pro I have:

```
myFiles.path=/final/destination
myFiles.files=*.cfg

INSTALLS += myFiles
```

Then

```
qmake myProject.pro
make install
```

will move all the .cfg files to /final/destination

Now I want to move this files to /final/destination just if they don't exists.

For example if /final/destination/myConf.cfg exists, don't replace it.

It's posible to do this adding some rule to myProject.pro?

I don't want to edit the Makefile, I want to mantain all the rules in the .pro if its possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Final/destination? Have you seen the movie?

Comment: I don't think qmake can do this. May be cmake can.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested, but if I understand your question correctly you need a way to test existence of a file. You should be able to use the function exists(/path/to/file)

found this example

```
EXTRAS = handlers tests docs
for(dir, EXTRAS) {
    exists($$dir) {
        SUBDIRS += $$dir
    }
}
```

from: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html